# Cube distortion

Tags: geometry, 3d, solid-geometry

EDIT1:

A unit cube ABCDEFGH has rods pinned at its 8 vertices. It is distorted by bringing together opposite vertices A and G ( initial distance AG $=\sqrt3 $ now reduced) thereby increasing angle  between spread out  edges at A and G from a right angle $90^{\circ}$to $\theta\le 120^{\circ }.$ None of the 6 quadrilaterals (skewed rhombuses) are in a plane.

What are the other 18 angles in terms of distance $x=AG?$ How are they computed?

A rough sketch ***before*** deformation with 8 ball joints $x= \sqrt 3$, and,

when AG$\;\to 0$ ***after*** full flattening  regular hexagon in the plane. Except these two all rhombuses are skewed, not planar or flat.

Thanks!

[image]

Comment: Why would the angles between edges at $A$ be $120^\circ$? In addition to bringing two vertices together, did we somehow flatten the portions of the cube near those vertices? There seems to be too much that we don't know about the nature of this "distortion".

Comment: If the angles are 120, then everything has become flat, and |AG|=0.

Comment: Ok .what are the other angles then? can I ask to genaralize? Hope not changing the goal post.

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: In fact made a crude paper model not good enough presentation..shall try to.

Comment: The faces all become rhombi with the four angles $\theta$,  $180-\theta$, $\theta$,  $180-\theta$. If you want to relate $\theta$ to $|AG|$, here's a hint: If you make two parallel cuts, one cutting plane through vertices BDE and the other through CFH, then AG is divided exactly into thirds. This cuts off two tetrahedra, and you can do all your calculations in these. Note that their bases are unchanged by the squashing along the $AG$ axis so are regular triangles with edge length $\sqrt{2}$.

Comment: "Access denied" when trying to follow the link.

Comment: I'm sorry, @DavidK, I still cant get it out of android, trying..

Comment: @JaapScherphuis@ Thanks. But a rhombus has to have its four vertices in the same plane. Also I would appreciate an expression for other angles as a function of AG; If AG is zero, as you say it all flattens out.

Comment: @Narasimham In that case you will have to precisely define what the distortion is. I assumed that the whole cube is contracted by a scaling operation along the direction of the AG diagonal.

Comment: Sorry for it, shall delete it, something is wrong.

Comment: @Jaap Scherphuis:  So made a physical model, the "rhombus" is skewed, the four boundaries are straight lines.

Comment: @JaapScherphuis: To me appears  distortion and scaling contractions are different. The corresponding angles change in a distortion.

Comment: I can see how the square faces **could** become skew polygons, since even in the initial cube configuration, you could rotate $\triangle ABC$ around the diagonal through $AC$ while rotating $\triangle EFG$ around $EG$ without moving $D$ or $H$. But I don't see the reason why the faces **must** become skew polygons.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the comment. Can we in that case include all deformation patterns as a function of some  distortion parameter?

Answer (score 3):

You can think of this distortion as a contraction scaling operation along $AG$, but combined with an expansion scaling in the other directions so that all the edges/rods remain the same length. A frame made from 12 rods and flexible joints has many more degrees of freedom, but provided that the arrangement of rods at $A$ look the same as those at $G$, and remain symmetrically arranged around the diagonal $AG$, then you will get a squashed cube with rhombus faces. In practice this is very hard to achieve since the slightest misalignment of any of the rods at $A$ or $G$ will cause the whole figure to become misshapen. These edges must not only have the same angles between each other, their angle to the $AG$ diagonal must also all be the same.

In a cube, the tetrahedron $ABDE$ has a height from vertex $A$ of $\frac{|AG|}3$. This will still be the case after the cube is squashed along $AG$. Assuming the edges remain of length $1$, you can use Pythagoras to find that the circumradius of triangle $BDE$ is $r = \sqrt{1-\frac{|AG|^2}9}$. The length of $BD$ is then $r\sqrt3$. This is also the long diagonal of a rhombus face, which makes the obtuse vertex angle equal to $\theta=2 \arcsin (\frac{r\sqrt{3}}2)$.

We can check that this calculation gives correct answers for the extreme cases.

$$|AG|=0 \implies r=1 \implies \theta=2 \arcsin (\frac{\sqrt{3}}2) = 2\cdot 60^\circ =120^\circ $$
$$|AG|=3 \implies r=0 \implies \theta=2 \arcsin 0 = 2\cdot 0^\circ =0^\circ $$
$$|AG|=\sqrt3 \implies r=\sqrt\frac23 \implies \theta=2 \arcsin (\frac{\sqrt{2}}2) = 2\cdot 45^\circ =90^\circ $$

Comment: Thanks. Can we get an expression for intermediate positions? Are we still on flat rhombuses?