# Cube Distortion 2

Tags: geometry, 3d, solid-geometry

A unit cube ABCDEFGH has rods/edges connected at its 8 vertices by means of flexible ball-joints enabling rotation with two degrees of freedom . It is distorted by bringing together opposite vertices (B,D) of top face simultaneously pulling apart opposite vertices (F,H) of bottom face so all four vertices move in plane BDHF.

EDIT1:

Distance *BD decreases and distance HF increases* from the initial distance  $=\sqrt2 $ by the same amount, say $\delta$. Angles  at B,D increase and those at H,F decrease by the same amount away from $90^{\circ}$. None of the 6 quadrilaterals (skewed rhombuses) are in a plane after deformation.

*Center of cube O in 3d space remains the same.*

In the extreme deformation the cube shrinks to a  radial tetrahedral  unit vector bundle of three unit rod lengths at angle $ \cos^{-1}({-1}/{3})$ to each other about the cube center. So the (origin centered) Cartesian coordinates of vector tips are:

$$\{(0,0,1),(-\sqrt 2/3, \sqrt6/3,-1/3), (-\sqrt 2/3,- \sqrt6/3,-1/3),(2\sqrt 2/3, 0,-1/3)\};$$

What are the other new 18 angles in terms of distance BD or HF? How can they be computed?  A rough sketch of pre-deformation situation is:

[image]

The question is similar to [Cube Distortion.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4513195/cube-distortion/4513747#4513747)

Thanks for all thoughts on it!

Comment: You say "none of the 6 quadrilaterals (skewed rhombuses) are in a plane after deformation" but that's not necessarily true: faces $ABCD$ and $EFGH$ could well be planar. You should add some more constraints to uniquely determine the transformation.

Comment: I think in the extreme deformation the cube becomes a cross, with line $ABCD$ perpendicular to line $EFGH$.

Comment: Can I request you for a 3d Geogebra simulation using a slider for collapsing the cube? I convinced myself about the geometry, but I could still be missing something. ( If something relevant occurs to me then I'll post it right away).

Comment: I can provide a GeoGebra simulation with two planar faces, is that what you want? As I wrote above, that is not the only possibility.

Comment: Agree, there are multiple solutions for $A,E,C,G$ given $B,D,F,H$ as described.

Comment: Anyway, here's a GeoGebra example, where top and bottom faces are planar: https://www.geogebra.org/m/zvgcyn6p

Comment: Did you perhaps mean all six skewed "faces" stay congruent among them, during the deformation? That constraint should imply uniqueness, I suppose.

Comment: Yes indeed,  thanks for the observation. Thought it was automatic... is it an error  specifically not mentioning it as a constraint?

Comment: I don't think it's obvious. Moreover, with that constraint distance $FH$ cannot always grow: it reaches a maximum and then decreases.

Comment: Am still  working on a model as a moving mechanism. It is so easily seen on the  physical (buckled) model but not that  readily reproducible on Geogebra with Move/Drag hand motions using mouse. Maybe Blender software is more suitable...

Comment: For which case? I did it for the all-faces-equal case with GeoGebra, if you are interested.

Comment: By the way, the constraint you mention:

• plane $BDHF$ is fixed;

• distance $BD$ increases and distance $HF$ decreases from the initial distance by the same amount;

• angles at $B$, $D$ increase and those at $H$, $F$ decrease by the same amount away from 90°;

are impossible to meet all at the same time. And imposing all skew faces are equal is still different, see my answer below.

Comment: Thanks..In EDIT1 I have corrected the simple typo. BD decreases and HF increases. Apologies if it created confusion. So to be clear earlier also indicated arrows towards each other at BD and away from each other  at HF.  Please feel free to point out any other inconsistency. *Also center of cube remains the same in space*.

Comment: Your correction doesn't change what I wrote above: such conditions are impossible to meet all at the same time. A fixed center is not a problem, of course. The animation I added to my answer has a fixed center, for instance. By the way: is that answer fine for you, or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all six skewed "faces" are kept congruent among them, during the deformation, then $BDEG$ are the vertices of a regular tetrahedron (green in figure below). If $x=BD$  is the length of its edges, then $x=\sqrt2\,l$ at the beginning of the distortion ($l$ is the edge of the cube) and $x=0$ at the end.

Points $ACFH$ are then the vertices of four equal pyramids, whose bases are the faces of the tetrahedron. It's easy to compute the height $h$ of these pyramids, because lateral edges have length $l$:
$$
h=\sqrt{l^2-{1\over3}x^2}
$$

$ACFH$ are also the vertices of a regular tetrahedron (not shown in the figure), whose edge $FH$ can be computed (with some geometry) as
$$
FH={x+2\sqrt{6l^2-2x^2}\over3}.
$$

The initial value is $FH=\sqrt2\,l$ and the final value is ${2\over3}\sqrt6\,l$, but it reaches a maximum of $FH=\sqrt3\,l$ for $x=l/\sqrt3$. Hence distance $FH$ doesn't keep increasing throughout the transformation.

[image]

EDIT.

Here's an animated picture of the transformation.

[image]

Comment: Beautiful. Interesting intermediate stage when $FH=\sqrt3\,l$ ( initial largest diagonal ) is maximum for $x=l/\sqrt3$.

Comment: @ Intelligenti pauca: Can you also please address the *Cube Distortion* from which this followed? (  Squeezed  maximum cube diagonal ).